# How to use SQL cummulative sum in PHP database update

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a simple account report with cumulative sum . I got the sql working in phpmyadmin . 
set @csum := 0;
    update accountssetup
    set BAL = (@csum := @csum + DR) WHERE Accounttype = 'EXPENSES' AND                date ='2019-07-19'
    order by id;

when i put this SQL in PHP

i get error

// i removed the connection part

```
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
// This is the where i am having issues ! ! !
$sql = "
set @csum := 0
update accountssetup
set BAL = (@csum := @csum + DR)
order by id;";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error; //$error ='1';

}
$conn->close();
```

I expect the Cummulative sum to work by updating BAL with the cumulative sum but i get this error

Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'update accountssetup set BAL = (@csum := @csum + DR) order by id' at line 2

Comment: What does 'DR' means on the 'bal =' line. My assumption is that the MySQL takes that 'DR' as a value. If that will be the case, adding numeric and string will cause error.

Comment: Which version of MariaDB do you use?

Comment: DR is a column in the table . It contains the values to be added to get the cumulative sum. It works perfectly when i insert the sql in phpmyadmin.  I only have issues when i put the sql in php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working perfectly guys thanks

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "appportal";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

}
$sql1 = "set @csum := 0";
$sql2 = "update accountssetup\n"

. "set BAL = (@csum := @csum + DR)\n"

. "order by id";

if ($conn->query($sql1)&& $conn->query($sql2) === TRUE)

{
echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
```

//$error ='1';

```
}
$conn->close();
                ?>
```

I actually used multi query by setting two variables . $sql1 and $sql2 . This allow the two Sql to run at the same time.

Comment: If someone wrote the correct answer, you should mark it as accepted rather than making a copy of it

Comment: Unless you have added more to this answer than the other  one? If so you should point out what you did, for the benefit of future readers who may have similar problems

Answer (score 1):

seems you missed  a semicolon after set 
use set = 0 (and not set := 0)   because is  an initialization and  try use () around (@csum + DR)

```
$sql = "
set @csum = 0;
update accountssetup
set BAL = (@csum := (@csum + DR));";
```

but be sure your db driver allow multiple sql statements in a a query
you don't need  order by

Comment: Still not working. I tired multi query  $sql $sql. Still not working

Comment: Yeah : Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'update accountssetup set BAL = (@csum := (@csum + DR))' at line 2

Comment: are you sure your db driver allow multiple statements ????  which php mysql driver you are using????

Comment: XAMPP for Windows 5.6.32 
    Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
    Server type: MariaDB
    Server version: 10.1.28-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
    Protocol version: 10
   
    Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: I think i have finally fix it !